# ¿Cómo crear una pirámide de asteriscos con dos argumentos en Java?

Tags: java, cmd

Me gustaria saber como podría realizar una pirámide de asteriscos de manera que al pasar un valor en el cmd me devuelva esa pirámide con los asteriscos correspondientes y que además al pasar los valores izquierda o derecha esta piramide se construya de izquierda a derecha o de derecha a izquierda.
Mi código es el siguiente,

````
    final static String LEFT = "left";
    final static String RIGHT = "right";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String ERROR_MUST_BE_INTEGER ="[ERROR] You must write an integer number!!";
        final String ERROR_MUST_BE_VALID_DIRECTION ="[ERROR] You must write a valid direction: LEFT or RIGHT!!";

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Write a number: ");
        String numberInput = in.next();

        System.out.println("Select direction: ");

        String direction = in.next();

        if(!isValidDirection(direction)) {
            System.err.println(ERROR_MUST_BE_VALID_DIRECTION);
            System.exit(1);
        }


        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);
            String result = upstair(number, direction);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println(ERROR_MUST_BE_INTEGER);
            System.exit(1);
        }                   


        in.close();
    }```

//Ahora tengo que hacerlo aquí paso a paso,
```public static boolean isValidDirection(String direction)```
```public static String upstairRight(int length)```
```public static String upstairLeft(int length)```
```public static String upstair(int length, String direction)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno por lo que entendí debes validar si es right o left para eso tu método isValidDirection debe regresar un valor `false` en caso de que no sea right o left.
Te quedaría algo así:

```
private static boolean isValidDirection(String direction) {
    if(direction.equals("LEFT") || direction.equals("RIGHT"))
    {
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
    }
```

Así cuando tu Dirección sea igual a RIGHT o LEFT(en mayúsculas específicamente)regresara un valor `True` y no se ejecutara tu `if` con el mensaje de error.
Ahora para construir la pirámide se utilizara un vector

```
String pyramid []= new String[number];
```

donde el tamaño del vector sera igual a la cantidad de escalones de la pirámide que se elija. Después se harán 2 variables

```
String result = "",character="";
```

donde result sera donde se guarde el resultado y character sera el carácter de tu piramide en este caso sera un asterisco "*". Luego se llenara el vector con asteriscos

```
for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        character+= "*";
        pyramid[i]=character;   
    }
```

Así el vector quedara lleno de esta manera claro que no estaría escalonado si no lineal pero cada elemento tendría guardado esos valores

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

ahora solo se almacena en la variable result para el caso que sea LEFT y se agrega un /n para hacer un salto de linea y ahora si que quede escalonado.

```
if(direction.equals("LEFT"))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
            result+=pyramid [i]+"\n";
        }
    }
```

y para RIGHT solo recorrerías tu vector al revés

```
else 
    {
        for(int i=number-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            result+=pyramid [i]+"\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
```

al final el código del método upstair quedaría así

```
private static String upstair(int number, String direction) {
    String pyramid []= new String[number];
    String result = "",character="";
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        character+= "*";
        pyramid[i]=character;   
    }
    if(direction.equals("LEFT"))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
            result+=pyramid [i]+"\n";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        for(int i=number-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            result+=pyramid [i]+"\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```